# Access Cell tower Objects using Telephony package in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, telephony, telephonymanager

I am trying to make geolocation request with API call (in react native) https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY.  This API takes following inputs in request body.

```
{
  "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
  "homeMobileNetworkCode": 410,
  "radioType": "gsm",
  "carrier": "Vodafone",
  "considerIp": "true",
  "cellTowers": [
    // See the Cell Tower Objects section below.
  ],
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
    // See the WiFi Access Point Objects section below.
  ]
}

{
  "cellTowers": [
    {
      "cellId": 42,
      "locationAreaCode": 415,
      "mobileCountryCode": 310,
      "mobileNetworkCode": 410,
      "age": 0,
      "signalStrength": -60,
      "timingAdvance": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to get all properties listed above except following using package Telephony and CarrierInfo in react native. It would be great if someone can locate the package and function to get these details in react-native.

```
     locationAreaCode    
     age
     signalStrength
     timingAdvance
```